# Responsive Site Design - Meta and MS viewport together?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, internet-explorer-10, viewport

I did read about this elegant CSS viewport definition:

```
@viewport{
    zoom: 1.0;
    width: extend-to-zoom;
}
```

Unfortunately it's not fully supported.

Could this piece be used together with the regular meta tag?:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

And what about:

```
@-ms-viewport{
    width: extend-to-zoom;
    zoom: 1.0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For creating a responsive website, the best combination would be the following tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

and the following css:

```
@-ms-viewport{
    width: device-width
}
```

This makes the website width equal to the user's device width on every modern browser.

If you have more questions, comment. If it helps, +1 and accept.

Comment: what about "maximun-scale-1"? I did read that it forces the "refresh" when you go from horizontal to vertical, or vice versa. Anyway, your answer helps (sorry for the delay. I got sick)